# Php and python regexp difference?

Tags: php, python, regex

I need to parse a string `'Open URN: 100000 LA: '` and get 100000 from it.
on python regexp `(?<=Open URN: )[0-9]+(?= LA:)` works fine but in php it gives following error:

```
preg_match(): Unknown modifier '['
```

I need it working php, so please help me to solve this problem and tell about difference in python and php regexps.

Comment: please post the exact php syntax of your `preg_match()`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) when you are using the [*Perl Compatible Regular Expressions* (PCRE) functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) in PHP (to which [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) belongs).

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by ***delimiters***. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

The reason for using delimiters is that you can add [**pattern modifiers**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) after the last delimiter, e.g. to make an case-insensitive match:

```
#[a-z]#i  // # is the delimiter.
```

---

**Back to your problem:**

In your case, PHP thinks the brackets `()` are your delimiters (yes, opening and closing brackets are valid delimiters, see the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)) and `?<=Open URN:` is your pattern . Then it encounters `[` and treats it as [pattern modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), but it is not a valid one.

Your pattern with delimiter `%`:

```
preg_match('%(?<=Open URN: )[0-9]+(?= LA:)%', 'Open URN: 100000 LA: ');
```

There are a lot examples in the [documentation of `preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

---

**Python vs PHP**

The only thing I found regarding regular expressions in Python is, that [Perl syntax is used](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#regex-howto) but I don't know if the full syntax is supported.
As already mentioned, PHP uses PCRE. [Description of the differences between PCRE and Perl regex.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php)

Comment: [php docs about delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Answer (score 1):

Except of mentioned differences I found one more.
re.match(r"\s", "a b") in python with preg_match("/\s/", "a b"), the first doesn't return matches in python while the second will find space symbol. I didn't find why in official docs, it's hard to understand but it's a fact.

Comment: Python's `match` method automatically anchors the match at the beginning, so `re.match(r"\s", "a b")` is equivalent to `preg_match('/^\s/', "a b")`.  For a plain old non-anchored match you have to use the `search` method: `re.search(r"\s", "a b")`